# How to implement simple string pattern-matching using standard libraries (including boost)

Tags: c++, boost, visual-c++-2008

I wish to add very simple pattern-matching functionality to some C++ code, e.g. I have a `map<string,int>` and want to write a method `sumMatchingEntries(string pattern)` which will sum all values where the key matches the input pattern. The pattern would be simple e.g. the only wildcards would be `*` and possibly `?`.

I believe boost has regex support but that seems a bit overkill, so are there any other standard library functions one might use?

Note I'm using VC++ 2K8 so no C++03/11 features, but boost is OK. If a regex solution is best, an example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

VC++2008 includes TR1 regexps as a feature pack: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26285/Quick-Start-for-C-TR1-Regular-Expressions.   Re-inventing the wheel is probably not worth it.

Comment: Not much use if anyone I work with is relying on the Express edition - I'm not really a fan of 'hacking' the compiler anyway - what's wrong with just suggesting I use boost?

Comment: Also I do NOT want the user entering regexps so I'd still have to come up with the regexp to do what I want... so a regex answer would be valid to my question.

Comment: You did not indicate that only express edition was an option, you need to be more precise in your questions.    Also, feel free to use Boost if you like it, it's a pretty heavy weight to any project though, but probably less pain than trying to write and debug REs yourself.